# How to compare input value from excel value and hghlight it using VBA?

Tags: vba

I had a variable named data that has a input value of = "Vince" ..

Then i want to compare data to the value in Excel and if there's the same value the excel value will be highlighted.

Summarize.
data = "Vince";

if cells.rows.value = data then

cell.rows.value.highlight.

End if

Answer (score 0):

I've included two options in this answer:

**OPTION 1** - Find and highlight all cells that contain "Vince" anywhere in the cell if they aren't already highlighted. For example, this will also highlight cells that contain "I am Vince", "Province", etc.

```
Sub FindAndHighlight1()

Dim FindCount   As Long
Dim curCell     As Range
Dim i           As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    FindCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "*Vince*")
    Set curCell = .Cells.Find(What:="Vince")
    For i = 1 To FindCount
        If curCell.Interior.Color <> 65535 Then curCell.Interior.Color = 65535
        Set curCell = .FindNext(curCell)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

**OPTION 2** - Find and highlight all cells that contain only "Vince" if they aren't already highlighted

```
Sub FindAndHighlight2()

Dim FindCount   As Long
Dim curCell     As Range
Dim i           As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    FindCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "Vince")
    Set curCell = .Cells.Find(What:="Vince")
    For i = 1 To FindCount
        If curCell.Value <> "Vince" Then
            i = i - 1
            Set curCell = .FindNext(curCell)
        ElseIf curCell.Interior.Color <> 65535 Then
            curCell.Interior.Color = 65535
            Set curCell = .FindNext(curCell)
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Change `"Vince"` and `What:="Vince"` to reference your variable if necessary, and change `Worksheets("Sheet1")` if necessary.